# How to start an interactive terminal window on mac using child_process library of node?

Tags: node.js, bash, typescript, .net-core, child-process

I want to execute a bash command - `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` in an interactive terminal through `child_process` library.
Since it asks for the user password, it has to be interactive terminal.

I've already tried using AppleScript for it, but the user experience is subpar since it tends to leave half-closed terminal windows around.

Edit - Added the code snippet that I am using to create a child_process.

```
import * as cp from 'child_process'
cp.spawn('dotnet dev-certs https --trust', {})
```

I've tried many many combinations of `cp.spawn` and `cp.exec`.
e.g. `cp.spawn('...', { shell: true, stdio: 'ignore', detached: true })` etc.

`cp.spawn` actually creates a process, but it's not interactive and immediately terminates.

Comment: Can you please add some code how you creating the child_process?

Comment: Added the code snippet!

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter the incoming data from stdout with **stdout.on('data', data => {})** to find the shell request for user input. After you found that specific line you can simply send data to the shell via the **stdin.write('any input \n')**

```
import * as cp from 'child_process'
const ls = cp.spawn('dotnet dev-certs https --trust', {})

    ls.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
       const currentData = data.toString();

       //check for password input notification:
       if(currentData === "input credentials: ")
       {
         //send the password via stdin. \n does the trick over here. 
         ls.stdin.write('Password\n');
       }  
    });
```